# Cannot Boot Ubuntu in UEFI Mode

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode in my laptop. I have downloaded the ISO file of Ubuntu and used Rufus to create a bootable drive with **MBR or GPT** option. When I tried to boot into the USB, all I am left is with the Grub Rescue terminal.

Here is the screenshots of the issue I am facing:

[image]

I have even tried to load it manually, but didn't help.

Please assist.

Comment: The USB is set to UEFI?

Comment: Yes. Formatted the USB as said by C.S.Cameron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I made the USB to boot in my PC.

As shared by @C.S.Cameron , the issue that I was encountering is because of the corrupted ISO image. I downloaded a new image and used it to boot in my PC.

**NOTE:** Verifying the ISO image with its corresponding MD5 or SHA256 checksum can save considerable amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

### Rufus Settings for UEFI Only Ubuntu Install

Note **Partition scheme** and **Target system** for UEFI only install.

[image]

Comment: I have tried the same. Didn't work either.

Comment: @Panther Coder:  Most of the reasons that a bootable USB might not be booting can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot

Comment: @PantherCoder And at least now you know the correct settings. You were using the option for BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode before.