# Clean install of Ubuntu from ISO doesnt run due to grub error 'grub_file_filters' not found

Tags: system-installation, grubrescue, usb-installation

Trying to install latest version of Ubuntu from ISO into bare metal machine.
machine is completely empty, one NTFS formatted HDD and one USB stick with Ubuntu ISO connected.

getting:

```
error: symbol 'grub_file_filters' not found'
entering rescue moode...
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue3pR.jpg)

I tried mounting (hd0, msdos1) as this is the USB stick.
didnt work.

what should I do?

more details: ISO was downloaded straight from Ubuntu official site: ubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64
used rufus to put it USB drive on NTFS.

Thank you.

Comment: NTFS? Installer is normally FAT32 and Rufus should have made that for you. The other alternative is a hybrid DVD/Flash drive configuration that has no partitions like a DVD. Most systems in last 10 years are UEFI, so you need gpt & UEFI boot for both installer & your install. Shows screen with gpt & UEFI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364249/cannot-boot-ubuntu-in-uefi-mode & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278772/unable-to-access-ubuntu-from-uefi  &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Use Etcher instead of Rufus.

Comment: My plausible solution here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1481948/1721410.

This answer works fine for a clean install or dual booting machine too.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

Problem was I was using a very old version of Rufus.

1. I used NTFS instead the default stuff Rufus gives.
2. Because the version was old, it tried getting some Grub updates. but the server didnt accept the older version so Grub was probably downloaded incorrectly.