# Newbie Ubuntu 22.04.2 on thumb drive "symbol 'grub_file_filters' not found"

Tags: boot, grubrescue

Linux noob here, although I do have some experience with BSD Unix.

I downloaded and created a bootable USB drive from "ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso" using Rufus.

When I boot my laptop from the USB drive, I get the following:

```
GRUB loading:
Welcome to GRUB!

error: symbol 'grub_file_filters' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

So after some poking around, I find the grub directory is under /boot, with normal.mod files under /boot/grub/i386-pc and x86_64-efi

Googling up some directions too get past this, I try:

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal
error: symbol 'grub_file_filters' not found
```

Now I'm stumped...

Any suggestions on how to get this thing to boot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean install of Ubuntu from ISO doesnt run due to grub error 'grub\_file\_filters' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377940/clean-install-of-ubuntu-from-iso-doesnt-run-due-to-grub-error-grub-file-filters)

Answer (score 2):

After some searching on this forum, I found that I was using a very old version of Rufus, v2.15, whereas the current version is 4.1

Solution:
[Clean install of Ubuntu from ISO doesnt run due to grub error 'grub_file_filters' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377940/clean-install-of-ubuntu-from-iso-doesnt-run-due-to-grub-error-grub-file-filters)

When re-creating the bootable USB drive, Rufus 4.1 downloaded a new version of Grub, and this USB drive boots okay

Answer (score 1):

*That looks like something is broken in what you're attempting to boot...*

To ensure that you actually got the ISO in expected state...

Re-download the image and the SHA256SUMS file from
https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/

After that do
`$ sha256sum SHA256SUMS` # or the corresponding on Windows
and you should see "OK" for the ISO you got.

**Then** make sure you get the ISO into the thumb-drive, and boot it.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem while dual booting Ubuntu 22.04 alongside an already existing Win10.
Laptop had these specs -
Bios: Legacy
Partition type: MBR

**Solution :**

1. use a recent version of Rufus (atleast above v4)
2. as per the above laptop specs mentioned, while creating Ubuntu 22.04's bootable; choose -

   - Partition Scheme = MBR
   - File System = FAT32
   - Cluster size = Default

PS: @alphax-anon 's answer works just right. Thanks!